# Why can't I import CSS files for my React server side rendering app?

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, server-side-rendering

The general error: `SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`, referencing line 1 of `index.css`.

This is the result of encountering CSS syntax in a CSS file that I'm trying to import for styling.

Attempted fixes and experiments:

1. Deleted everything out of the CSS file and exported an empty JS module. This works, verifying that the import is treating it as a JS file, not CSS.
2. Removing the @import statement from line 1 of the CSS file. Of course, this fails to make a difference because the remaining CSS syntax throws the same error.
3. Paired down the Webpack config file to eliminate the surface area of the problem. Rendering should be handled by Webpack, so the issue may reside there. Config was very basic and set to handle CSS, SASS, JS, and JSX.
4. Tried importing the CSS file from other file locations, including the server's app.js file.
5. Tried making use of [ExtractTextPlugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin) as an bundling alternative.
6. Tried making use of [Isomorphic Style Loader](https://github.com/kriasoft/isomorphic-style-loader).

All in all, given the attempted fixes and tests listed above, the issue seems unrelated to Webpack per se. It's as if the server side rendering is attempting to import the CSS file before Weback gets involved.

Answer (score 4):

The fix, it turns out, was to use the [ignore-styles](https://github.com/bkonkle/ignore-styles) package in our server `app.js` file:

`require('ignore-styles')`

The description as listed on the repo:

> A babel/register style hook to ignore style imports when running in Node. This is for projects that use something like Webpack to enable CSS imports in JavaScript.